# I want to add a new terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, terminal

I want to add multiple terminals in my Visual Studio Code so that when I click on **New Terminal** I should get `git-bash` as my 1st terminal and Windows `cmd` as my 2nd terminal. I followed the tutorial on [Visual Studio Code Terminals Configuration.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9C3M0XlndM)

and tried to add a new terminal but the only thing I can see while adding a new terminal is `git-bash`. Here is my settings.json file content:

```
{
    "vsicons.presets.foldersAllDefaultIcon": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe",
    "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
    "gitlens.mode.active": "zen",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast"
},
{
    "vsicons.presets.foldersAllDefaultIcon": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
    "gitlens.mode.active": "zen",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast"
}
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 options. But after reload VSC this settings are removed and every start you need repeat this steps. If you finde how do this pls complement my answer.

**Option 1**

**1) remove second terminal from settings.json.** Now in terminal-list (right side of Terminal panel) you have only git-bash.
**2) rename path from git-bash to cmd.exe.**
**3) in terminal panel right side click on button "new terminal"**. You will see cmd.exe as second terminal.

---

**Option 2**

**1) ctrl+shift+p**. For open console in top side.
**2) Write: "Terminal: Select Default Shell"**. You will see all terminals.
**3) select terminal from list.**
**4) in terminal panel right side click on button "new terminal"**. You will see another terminal